# How to install JV Twitter module on Joomla 1.5?

Tags: twitter, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

It is said elsewhere, that [JV Twitter module](http://demo.joomlavi.com/extensions16/jv-twitter.html) is compatible with `Joomla` 1.5.

Unfortunately, the archive I got does not install.

The archive content is follows:

[image]

And the error message is "Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package.":

[image]

The content of XML file starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5" method="upgrade">
    <name>JV Twitter</name>
    <author>JoomlaVi! Project</author>
    <creationDate>May 2014</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) JoomlaVi. All rights reserved</copyright>
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenseses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL or later</license>
    <authorEmail>info@joomlavi.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.joomlavi.com</authorUrl>
    <version>4.0.8</version>
    <description>JV Twitter</description>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_jvtwitter">mod_jvtwitter.php</filename>
        <filename>helpers.php</filename>
        <filename>jvtwitter.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <folder>assets</folder>
        <folder>libs</folder>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <folder>fields</folder>
        <folder>languages</folder>
    </files>
    <languages folder="languages">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_jvtwitter.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_jvtwitter.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
    <config>
```

and so on.

Does this mean that actually package is not compatible with 1.5? Or it is still possible to do something?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the [developer website](http://joomlavi.com/joomla-extensions/social.html) and this module is only compatible with Joomla 2.5 and 3.x. It will not work for Joomla 1.5 as the XML structure and content is different in the 2 versions, so you will need to find an alternative.

I would strong suggest you think about migrating to Joomla 3.x very soon. It's more secure and has more features. You may have already noticed that not many developers still support Joomla 1.5